# set page size on collection while only getting in-stock items

Tags: collection, product-collection, stock

how do i load a collection in magento that is limited to 10 products but only includes products that are in stock?

what i tried

1:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize(10);

 Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
       ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
 // problem with this method - if one of the ten items are not in stock my
 // collection only has 9 items
```

*problem with this method - if one of the ten items are not in stock my collection only has 9 items*

2:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->joinField('qty',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'qty',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
             'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));
// problem with this method - configurable parent products don't have stock 
// (only the children do), this causes the parents not to show
```

*problem with this method - configurable parent products don't have stock (only the children do), this causes the parents not to show*

Any suggestions?

**Solution**

Here is a more fleshed out version of the correct answer below:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->joinField('is_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array("eq" => 1))
        ->setPageSize(10);
```

Comment: One crappy way to do this is just grab a larger number in your first approach, and only loop through the first 10 when you use them.

Comment: agreed, but sometimes you don't know how many it will go through to find it and you don't want to load the whole collection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_in_stock` should probably used to determined if something is in stock, instead of the `qty` you're using in the join. See below method for Magento's approach.

See `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock::setInStockFilterToCollection` for details.